# How to store a variable in an array in a different file

Tags: arrays, node.js, fs, fwrite

What I've done/tried so far:

I've created a file called `links.js` which contains a single array.

I've got my main file (index.js) which you run and it scrapes URLs;
I need to save the URL in links.js in the format I created so I can run the second part of my program which requires `links.js` in a specific format and uses the URLs gathered from my `index.js`

I've tried fs and creating streams etc but I'm still learning nodejs so I don't really understand it and can't find an issue on stack similar enough to figure out what to do..

Overview of format required for the links.js file expanding the url array each time with another url from index.js:
This is the `links.js` array format I need it in as an example

```
url = ['url1.com','url2.com','url3.com'];

module.exports{url:url};
```

How would I code my index.js so it stores my variable in the format above in links.js (a different file from the one I'm in)?

my index.js currently stores the url in `test2[1]`

I'm able to verify that's what I want to store by doing `console.log(test2[1]);`

Sorry if that's hard to understand I'm not sure how to explain it much better but if you're confused about something let me know and I'll try and reword it!

Thanks for any help :)

Expectations/Desired Outcomes:
I expect test2[1] to return http://example.com on index.js
I expext index.js to then save test2[1] and put it in links.js but keeping the format of links.js as explained and shown above.

I expect it to not be overwritten as index uses pupeteer and loops through to get website URLs and each would need to be saved all in the single links.js folder just expanding the arrays size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it as a json file.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const file = "./urls.json"

const urls = require(file )

//Here you update urls array
urls.push("url4.com")

fs.writeFileSync(file, JSON.stringify(urls))
```

urls.json

```
["url1.com","url2.com","url3.com", "url4.com"]
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried your suggestion in it's own empty file but couldn't get it to run without errors...
Also, I think I needed the file to be in .js format to use it how I intended?

Comment: As I make use of the array in another file by then calling `url[i]` after looping through and counting the number of urls in the file to determine what the value of I should be

Comment: I'm sorry. I fixed it. :) Try again :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reponse! Thank you, your answer got the job done!! haha :)